# MFMailComposeViewController customize

Tags: ios, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am customizing MFMailComposeViewController it is working fine in ios 5.0 and ios 5.1 but not working properly in ios 6. The  custom send and cancel button does not appear in mailcontroller.

My code is :

```
sendBtn = mailer.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem;
cancelBtn = mailer.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem;
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

UINavigationItem *mailVCNavItem = [mailer.navigationBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

        // Get the old bar button item to fetch the action and target.
UIBarButtonItem *oldCancelBarButton = [mailVCNavItem leftBarButtonItem];

        // Create your new custom bar button item.
        // In my case I have UIButton with image set as a custom view within a bar button item.
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel-button-hover.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:oldCancelBarButton.target action:oldCancelBarButton.action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 55, 28)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];

UIButton *sendbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[sendbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"send-btnComment.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sendbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(sendMail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[sendbtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 55, 28)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:sendbtn];
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working properly? What is the error message?

Comment: not any error is shown but custom send and cancel button is not appear in mailcontroller

Answer (score 1):

`MFMailComposeViewController` and the related Facebook and Twitter sharing views are implemented through remote view controllers in iOS 6. This means that the controllers are run in another process and it is no longer possible to customize them by accessing their properties or subviews directly. You can still do so through `UIAppearence` though, but what you are trying to with replacing the buttons is no longer possible in iOS 6.